# what I need is to wrap "return InkWell" in a card - flutter

Tags: flutter

**How do I wrap InkWell in a Card, I need InkWell to be wrapped in a card:**

```
card : Card(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              fit: StackFit.loose,
```

```
    //add Card
    return InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
            url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          ),
        ),
          ),
          child: Expanded(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: (_, __) {
                return Center(
                  child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                    radius: 15,
                  ),
                );

              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Just wrap your `InkWell` with a `card`? I didn't understand your problem. What do you want to do exactly, also update your question title, it's convoluted

Comment: yes, what I need is to wrap "return InkWell" in a card

Comment: Just write `Card(child: InkWell....`, If you mean the `return InkWell` then add a builder to card `Card(child: Builder(builder: (context) { return InkWell(...);}`

Comment: but how would it look with the current code

Comment: @Giovanny I think you don't know the basics of flutter & dart. I suggest revise the basics first. If you want to return `InkWell` then do that in a function or make a separate widget class and then return `InkWell`. You can't return a widget(`InkWell`) from another widget(`Card`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to wrap Inkwell in Card

```
return Card(
   child: InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );

          },
        ),
      ),
    )
)
```